# Vector in function format

Tags: vector-spaces

Not sure how to interpret the follow:

Find the intersection point(s)

of the line $r(t)=(0, -2, -1)+t(1, 1, 1)$ and the plane $x+2y-4z=-3$

Does $r(t)=(0, -2, -1)+t(1, 1, 1)$ mean $r=(0, -2t, -t)$?

Comment: No. $t(1,1,1)=(t,t,t)$. Now add it to first vector and $r(t) = (0 + t, -2 + t, -1 + t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice,

The parametric point of the line: $r(t)=(0, -2, -1)+t(1, 1, 1)$ is $(t+0, t-2, t-1)$ Since the line intersects the plane: $x+2y-4z=-3$ hence the point will satisfy the equation of plane.

Now, substituting the coordinates of point $(t, t-2, t-1)$ in the equation of the plane we get $$(t)+2(t-2)-4(t-1)=-3$$ $$t+2t-4-4t+4=-3$$$$\implies t=3$$ Now, substituting the value of $t$, the point of intersection of line & plane is given as $$(t, t-2, t-1)\equiv (3, 3-2, 3-1 )\equiv (3, 1, 2)$$ $$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\text{point of intersection}\equiv (3, 1, 2)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$r(t) = (t,t-2,t-1) \to x = t, y = t-2, z = t-1 \to t+2(t-2)-4(t-1) = -3\to -t=-3\to t = 3 \to (x,y,z) = (3,1,2)$ is the intersection point.